# Walk up the directory tree

Tags: elisp

The file tree is as follwing:

```
- foo
  - lorem
    - ipsum <-
  - baz <-
- bar
- baz
```

The currently visited file is `ipsum`. Now I want to find the first
`baz` and the directory it is in. How do I walk up the tree from
`ipsum` in elisp?

Comment: "First" is ambigous, not in this example, but generally. If there are multiple, should we prefer a child, a parent, or one of the sibling nodes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want `locate-dominating-file`.

Comment: Looks nice, except it does not seem to accept wildcards. I'm looking for a file with a given extension.

Comment: Actually, in recent versions of Emacs, it accepts a function as argument, so it can definititely do the widlcard thing (via `directory-files`).

Comment: `(locate-dominating-file DIR (lambda (parent) (directory-files parent nil "\\(GNU\\)?[Mm]akefile")))`

Answer (score 18):

```
(defun parent-directory (dir)
  (unless (equal "/" dir)
    (file-name-directory (directory-file-name dir))))

(defun find-file-in-heirarchy (current-dir fname)
  "Search for a file named FNAME upwards through the directory hierarchy, starting from CURRENT-DIR" 
  (let ((file (concat current-dir fname))
        (parent (parent-directory (expand-file-name current-dir))))
    (if (file-exists-p file)
        file
      (when parent
        (find-file-in-heirarchy parent fname)))))
```

If the result is not nil, you can extract the file's directory using `file-name-directory`, like so:

```
(let ((file (find-file-in-heirarchy (buffer-file-name) "baz")))
  (when file
    (file-name-directory file)))
```