# Get parent directory of path in Elisp

Tags: directory, emacs

I'm trying to find the parent directory of a user-given string `str` to check if it exists. I can find this easily with `(file-name-directory str)`. My issue is I also want to get the parent directory if they pass something with a trailing slash, like `"~/Projects/newdir/"` would hopefully get `"~/Projects/"` spit out instead of `"~/Projects/newdir/"`. I can't seem to find anything like this inside the Emacs documentation.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9555/2526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`directory-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Names.html):

```
(file-name-directory "/usr/bin/cc")
==> "/usr/bin/"
(directory-file-name (file-name-directory "/usr/bin/cc"))
==> "/usr/bin"
(file-name-directory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory "/usr/bin/cc")))
==> "/usr/"
(directory-file-name (file-name-directory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory "/usr/bin/cc"))))
==> "/usr"
```

and [`file-exists-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html):

```
(file-exists-p "/usr/bin/cc")
==> t
(file-exists-p "/usr/bin/")
==> t
(file-exists-p "/usr/bin")
==> t
(file-exists-p "/usr/bin/no such file")
==> nil
```

See also

- [Walk up the directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14095189/850781)
- [Function that returns parent directory absolute path](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9554/795)
- [Distinguishing Kinds of Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Kinds-of-Files.html)

Comment: `directory-file-name` does not give the parent directory, but changes an alternative representation of a directory.

Comment: @AttRigh: please see code examples.